# If (Q+S) = 10, Q & S being distinct positive integers. Find the greatest value of Q^S.

Tags: number-theory, optimization

I get stuck when I do this :

( 10 - S)^S  is the only line I can get myself.  I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Does `^` mean exponentiation or the binary $XOR$?

Comment: There are only $10$ values to check!

Comment: In fact only $8$, since the numbers must be positive and $(5,5)$ is disallowed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  too early in the morning for proper subtraction, I say.

Comment: To be clear:  analytic methods aren't terribly effective here.  You can take $f(x)=x\ln(10-x)$ and try to solve $f'(x)=0$ but that requires numerical methods as well.  Even then, you have to make a special argument to show why it suffices to just try the two integers on the sides of the real max.